# Why did Mulder forget about that room full of hybrids?

Tags: the-x-files

In *The X-Files* Season 1 finale "The Erlenmeyer Flask", Mulder and Scully learn the following:

> **DEEP THROAT:** Doctor Berube was killed because his work was too **successful**. You're standing in the room where the first DNA transplant took, **the first human-alien hybrid** was created.

[image]

However, in the Season 6 episode "Two Fathers", we have the following:

> **MULDER:** I believe Cassandra Spender represents the final stages of these experiments — that she may very well be the **first successful alien-human hybrid.**

And in the sequel episode "One Son":

> **MULDER:** She's the first, isn't she? She's the **first successful alien-human hybrid.**

**Why would Mulder ignore the existence of the previous group of**

> **successful hybrids and believe that Cassandra was the first?**

Comment: Perhaps it’s the difference between first and *first successful*. Maybe the first one died screaming within a week?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : The first ones were humans dying of incurable diseases until they became hybrids.  After hybridization, their illnesses went away and they developed "inhuman strength and the ability to breathe underwater", according to Deep Throat...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : One of the patients, Dr. William Secare, seemed to have been living a good life out in the real world as a hybrid until he was discovered (he should have been in storage like the others, but Dr. Berube was his friend and hybridized him as a favour so he would survive his cancer).  After Secare was found by police, he was shot and had to spend three days underwater.  Even then, it seemed that he would recover and survive (he was noticeably better when Mulder found him in the attic).  He only died because he was *executed* via a shot to the neck by a man in black.

Comment: *In many ways, Secare seems to have been a more successful hybrid than Cassandra.*

Comment: welp, there goes my theory.

Comment: The [Alien-human hybrid section of the "Colonist" wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonist_(The_X-Files)#Alien-human_hybrids) seems to try to reconcile it by distinguishing people who are either clones with some alien DNA or "partial hybrids", a group which includes William Secare and Samantha Mulder, vs. Cassandra who is said to represent the "pinnacle" of a new type of hybridization project being done on her abductions. Still, the distinction doesn't seem that clear, hopefully someone can find some lines from an episode or an interview with one of the writers that clarifies this.

Comment: @Praxis - I haven't watched the show in a while so I don't really remember enough details to add anything beyond what's stated in the article, but if you or anyone else wants to write up an answer that elaborates a little on that summary of the different types of hybrids and how they were created, suggesting why Cassandra might be more "complete" than the other ones, go for it.

Comment: Note that Deep Throat didn't say "The first successful alien-human hybrid is in this room right now in one of these tanks" He simply says that the first was created in that room. This leads to the conclusion that Cassandra Spender became the first successful alien-human hybrid in the same room where the tanks were at some point before Mulder was there.